# Emails issues when using TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, tempdata

I am using MVC 4, C# and Razor for a website I am currently building and am running into a strange problem.

The problem is relating to the code below:

```
Mailer.EmailAdmin(this, model);
Mailer.EmailUser(this, model);

TempData["Message"] = "Your request has been forwarded to the appropriate administrator." 
+ " \n You will be notified when the application has been processed.";
```

Both the above methods reach their respective breakpoints and the data is passed to the relevant model as anticipated. However, although both methods seem to work only one email is being sent out, this is always 'EmailUser' (no matter whether the Admin or User emails are put first). Please note, minus the views being different within the mailer the code to send the emails are exactly the same.

As soon as 'TempData' is removed from the code, both emails are sent without any problems what so ever.

Has anyone got any suggestions on why this may be occurring and a potential fix if their is one?

I am not using MVCMailer and am instead using a typical string builder to render the views in an email format. TempData is only being used as it needs to persist from ActionResult to another.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I like to carry objects from action to action...
Create a class...

```
    public class MessageModel
    {
        public virtual string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

In my first action result..

```
 var mModel = new SelectionModel.MessageModel
            {
                Message = "my message"
            };

        Session["mModel "] = mModel;
```

To change the message if you want or continue to use the same message...

```
 var mmModel = (SelectionModel.MessageModel)Session["mModel"];
        mmModel.Message = "new message";
        Session["mModel"] = mmModel;
```

you get the point..Not a big fan of tempdata...

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you do not use and/like TempData? 

It just seems from your own custom session handler for messages it's acting similar to TempData by storing the data in a session variable and then discarding it once its been used.

Comment: yes its does store it in session BUT once you read it ...poof.. its gone

Comment: If you need data to persist for one request, than use Tempdata, outside of that I like determining how long I keep stuff..

Answer (score 1):

You could probably avoid tempdata and session altogether by instead storing the text in a property on a view model, which is generally a better practice than using session. I assume you are storing the message in temp data to later display it to the user. Then you could instead do something like this:

```
public ActionResult SendEmail(MyModel model) {
    Mailer.EmailAdmin(this, model);
    Mailer.EmailUser(this, model);

    MyOtherModel otherModel = new MyOtherModel();
    otherModel.Message = "Your request has been forwarded to the appropriate administrator." 
    + " \n You will be notified when the application has been processed.";

    return View("MyView", otherModel);
}
```

Of course, you could also use the same model if the same model applies, or return a partial view instead of a full view. With a partial view you could combine it with ajax to display the message without refreshing the page (by replacing an existing div on the page with the ajax response, which would be the partial view).  If the text is not dynamic and always the same, you could also just put it in the partial view directly instead of storing it on the model.